# Why is the Condition excectuted in the tutorial of screep

Tags: javascript, screeps

I am Programming a lot in Python and just started playing around with Screeps and Javascript.

In the tutorial, this code is used to move a creep to an energy resource and harvets it:

```
if(creep.store.getFreeCapacity() > 0) {
        var sources = creep.room.find(FIND_SOURCES);
        if(creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
            creep.moveTo(sources[0]);
        }
    }
```

And the creep will do exactly that. However, in my intuition, the creep should not start harvesting because it is only told to move there. Is that something unique to how the objects are defined in Screeps, or something I am misunderstanding JavaScript.

I also tried to move the creep to the source without the if statement to check whether it will automatically harvest, but it does not do it.

Comment: is this code in some sort of loop? I'm guessing here, but it seems like if the creep isn't in range of the harvest, it will move there. Then maybe if the code if run again - `creep.harvest(sources[0])` will not equal out of range since the creep moved to it, so the creep will start harvesting.

Comment: yes you are right it is run in a constant loop.

creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE would return False at some point. But why would it execute the creep.harvest(sources[0]) , it would just evaluet to False and in my mind nothing should happen

Comment: You were right I tested it

Comment: tough to know without seeing the code for it, so I'm guessing that at some point `creep.harvest` will initiate the action of harvesting, only if there are no errors. If there is an error it will return the error instead of doing the action of harvesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harvest code can also be pulled apart instead of putting it in a single line. Maybe that will make it clear for you.

```
if(creep.harvest(sources[0]) == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
    creep.moveTo(sources[0]);
}
```

This part tells the creep to harvest and only after that evaluates the result of that harvest. The [documentation](https://docs.screeps.com/api/#Creep.harvest) says the method returns a constant result which can be checked.

Pulling this code apart a bit, it looks like this:

```
let harvestResult = creep.harvest(sources[0]);
if (harvestResult == ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
    creep.moveTo(sources[0]);
}
```

Now it's a bit clearer that the method is always called and evaluated after.